# Is it possible to hide the IP address in a PHP connection?

Tags: proxy, ip, php

Long story short, I'm wanting to test my site's anti-bot systems ("bot" here referring to players of the game cheating with programs, not spiders etc.).

I've written my own bot using PHP's CLI. Most of the time, my site is able to detect the bot activity and block it.

However I need to test dealing with dynamic IPs, and since I have a static one this is no easy task as far as I can tell. There are other things I'd like to be able to test that involve multiple IPs.

So, bottom line, is it possible to hide/change the IP address seen by the server when my PHP script connects to it and, if so, how do I do it? (I've never really used proxies before so I don't know much about them).

Comment: You can use the paid proxy solutions, something like this http://proxy.lc/

Comment: Y the downvote this was an intersting question?? +1

Comment: @Stewie any shh connection can be tunnelled to socks no need for "paid" solution

Comment: +1 I'm with @tomexsans. And if you're going to downvote, don't be an anonymous troll. At least attach your handle to it and explain your logic in a comment. Censure only works if you teach the offending party why you did it and how you think they can avoid it in the future.

Comment: I agree with @tomexsans and @ rdlowrey. Please cite the reason.. this is an excellent question.

Comment: Okay, here is the reason. "testing" is a weak excuse. One who really need to test, either can use dummy IPs hardcoded in the script or just *put the code on the production* and test it (and tune) in the real environment which would be a lot more reliable test. Hiding Ip address is indeed interesting question. For fraud, spam and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can write a test code which does substitute $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] at the very beginning of your script and do whatever tests you like.

Comment: cool hack, one can get a list of ip addresses by random geographical locations and set them randomly..

Comment: Definitely a far better solution than trying to mess with proxies (which don't seem like they would accomplish the goal of the question).

Answer (score 1):

No, IP is the one of the few things client can't camouflage.

Comment: duh ? Not true. One can use proxy servers to route the requests

Comment: Caveat: You can camouflage an IP if you have no interest in receiving a response (hence use of IP spoofing in DOS attacks etc)

Comment: Who said anything about camouflage. quote from the user: "So, bottom line, is it possible to hide/change the IP address seen by the server when my PHP script connects to it"

Comment: hide/change ~= camouflage isn't it

Comment: Proxy could be be considered camouflage, definition 3. "a device or stratagem used for concealment" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/camouflage

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Proxy severs. There are many open proxy servers that are available, but those are not reliable and slow.  You can use the paid proxy solutions, something like this proxy.lc